# "Error: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined." Error in Reactjs even my Export and file sturcture is correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am beginner to Reactjs . I am making a Login page in Reactjs for which I have made another folder "Components" in "src" folder . Inside "Components" folder I made a "LoginSignUp.js" component . I have imported this componen in "App.js" in "src" folder correctly (I hope) .

I found 2 solutions on stackoverflow regarding it . 1st solution is that function is not correctly exported and imported - but I found out that export & import is correct,I had also checked the spelling . 2nd solution is to restructure everything again until unless error is gone - I moved "LoginSignUp" to "src" folder but again no solution . Both of these solution didn't work for me .
Anyone knows where's the problem or something am I  overlooking ? It will be really a great help . I am anxious about this problem for last 2 hours.

Complete Error :
[image]

Here's my "src" folder strucute :

[image]

Here's My "LoginSignUp.js" :

```
import React from 'react'
import {Card} from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../styles/LoginSignUp.css';
function LoginSignUp() {
      return (
            <Card>
                  <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title><i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></Card.Title>
                        <Card.Subtitle>Login</Card.Subtitle>
                        <Card.text>
                        <label>
                              <i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                              </label>
                        </Card.text>
                  </Card.Body>
            </Card>
      );
}
export default LoginSignUp;
```

"App.js":

```
import LoginSignUp from './components/LoginSignUp';
import './styles/App.css';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <LoginSignUp/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thanking You

Yours Truly,

Rishabh Raghwendra

Comment: What's your react version??

Comment: @AnilLoutombam it's 4.0.1

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in  file 'LoginSignUp.js'.
You should replace `<Card.text> to <Card.Text>`

Comment: You have asked almost ten questions so far and got qualified answers in few of them but you didn't care to accept none of them as an answer @Rishabh Raghwendra. Given that If any answer solves your issue, make sure to accept that answer by pressing the greyed out chekmark. This is [how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/673712) you can. Thanks.